# loop to check combination of dropdown & checkbox in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, checkbox, dropdown

Good morning!
I have a page with 1 dropdown menu that has 24 options to select.
As well There are 12 checkboxes to select.
Each dropdown option and each checkbox has a predefined variable.
i.e.:
dropdown `value="utcValue0` ->  `var utc0` and
checkbox value `id="gameCheck"` -> `var gameTag`
desired output here is a new variable `var a = utc0 + gameTag`;

My current solution works, however it is very tedious and terrible to read and there must be a whole lot easier way to handle this. I'm at the moment just defining each scenario 1 by 1.
Considering it's 24 dropdown menus and 12 checkboxes this can not be the way..
I think it can be done with a smart nested loop, but I can't come up with how to actually write that.

I'd highly appreciate some help! Thank you so much!

```
    <select name="hourSelector" id="hourSelectorID">
      <option value="utcValue0">0 - 1 UTC</option>
      <option value="utcValue1">1 - 2 UTC</option>
      <option value="utcValue2">2 - 3 UTC</option>
      <option value="utcValue3">3 - 4 UTC</option>                
      <option value="utcValue4">4 - 5 UTC</option>
      <option value="utcValue5">5 - 6 UTC</option>
    </select>
```

```
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="gameCheck">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="purchCheck">
       <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="inputCheck">
```

```
    var utc0 = 'something';
    var utc1 = 'something';
    var utc2 = 'something';
    var utc3 = 'something';
    var utc4 = 'something';
    var utc5 = 'something';
    //var utcX = 'created>"' + todayUTC + 'T00:00:00Z"' + ' ' + 'created<"' + todayUTC + 'T01:00:00Z"';
```

```
var gameTag = 'whatever';
var purchTag = 'otherwhatever';
var eventTag = 'morewhatver';
```

```
  // grab input Hour
  var hourDropdown = document.getElementById("hourSelectorID");
  var selectedHour = hourDropdown.options[hourDropdown.selectedIndex].value;

    if (document.getElementById('gameCheck').checked) {
      if (selectedHour == 'utcValue0' ) {
        var a = utc0 + eventTag
      }
      if (selectedHour == 'utcValue1') {
        var a = utc1 + eventTag
      }
      if (selectedHour == 'utcValue2') {
        var a = utc2 + eventTag
      }
      if (selectedHour == 'utcValue3') {
        var a = utc3 + eventTag
      }
      if (selectedHour == 'utcValue4') {
        var a = utc4 + eventTag
      }
      if (selectedHour == 'utcValue5') {
        var a = utc5 + eventTag
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't clearly understand your requirement, but have you looked at storing the options in array, and using `foreach` or `filter` method.

Comment: What is the value of `todayUTC` and can only one radio button be toggled at the time?

Comment: @Esszed in fact the value of todayUTC is not really relevant. For making it simpler I edited my post and replaced the entire value of the var = utc0 / utc1 etc with a generic 'something'.

Yes, multple checkboxes can be checked. Up to 12.

Comment: @ShogonBCN it seems relevant because you are iterating the time in the string with every UTC, that can be done dynamically to avoid repetition. Aka avoiding creating 24 variables of `utcX` So if all three checkboxes are checked the result should be `utc4 + gameTag + purchTag + eventTag`?

Comment: @Esszed

`var dateUTC = new Date();`

`todayUTC = dateUTC.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (('0' + dateUTC.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dateUTC.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);`

That is the content of todayUTC.
Maybe I need to rework the entire question a bit.
The desired output is actually multiple outputs. One for each checkbox checked.
i.e. when all checkboxes are checked:
`utcX + gameTag` and 
`utcY + purchTag` and 
`utcZ + eventTag`
etc

Comment: @ShogoBCN I edited my answer to include the `todayUTC` variable. Does it provide the desired output?

Comment: not exactly 1:1 as I need it in my application, but the provided logic is exactly what I was looking for. I can make some small adjustments and implement it into my project.
Thank you soooooo much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have changed your question so I'm not sure with what follows. Drop a comment below for adjustments or questions :-)

```js
var formEl = document.getElementById("form");
var selectEl = document.getElementById("hourSelectorID");
var checkboxEls = Array.prototype.slice.call(
  document.getElementsByClassName("custom-control-input")
);

// option elements

for (let i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  let optionEl = document.createElement("option");
  optionEl.value = "utcValue" + i;
  optionEl.textContent = i + " - " + (i + 1) + " UTC";
  selectEl.appendChild(optionEl);
}

// form submit

formEl.addEventListener("submit", function (ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  console.log(toStringStuff());
});

// rename as needed :-)

function toStringStuff () {
  var now = Date.now(); // in ms
  var hourInMs = 1000 * 60 * 60;
  var dayInMs = hourInMs * 24;
  var today = now - now % dayInMs; // `now` with time set to 0
  var i = selectEl.selectedIndex; // hours to add to `today`
  var dt0 = new Date(today + i * hourInMs).toISOString();
  var dt1 = new Date(today + (i + 1) * hourInMs).toISOString();
  var utc = 'created>"' + dt0 + ' ' + 'created<"' + dt1;
  return [utc].concat(checkboxEls.filter(
    function (el) { return el.checked; }
  ).map(
    function (el) { return el.value; }
  )).join(" ");
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <select
    id="hourSelectorID"
    name="hourSelector"
  ></select>
  <label><input
    id="gameCheck"
    type="checkbox"
    class="custom-control-input"
    value="gameTag"
    checked
  > Game Check</label>
  <label><input
    id="purchCheck"
    type="checkbox"
    class="custom-control-input"
    value="purchTag"
    checked
  > Purch Check</label>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: As the previous solution this is also a great way to handle my application with some adaption.
Thank you so much for the code. I learned a lot from this! <3

Comment: @ShogoBCN Glad you enjoy and learn something thanks to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution taking advantage of the options indexes matching the itteration of the string. It takes the index of the selected option and changes the string accordingly while concatenating the values from selected checkboxes.

```js
let dateUTC = new Date(); 
let todayUTC = dateUTC.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + (('0' + dateUTC.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + dateUTC.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);

const select = document.querySelector("#hourSelectorID");
const allCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="chkBox"]');
const elements = [...allCheckboxes, select]

elements.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener("change", () => {
    let checkedValues = []
    const checked  = [...allCheckboxes].filter(cb => cb.checked);
    checked.forEach(cb => checkedValues.push(cb.value))
    console.log(`created>" ${todayUTC} T0${select.selectedIndex}:00:00Z" created<" ${todayUTC} T0${select.selectedIndex+1}:00:00Z" ${checkedValues.join(' ')}`)   
  });
});
```

```html
<select name="hourSelector" id="hourSelectorID">
  <option value="utcValue0">0 - 1 UTC</option>
  <option value="utcValue1">1 - 2 UTC</option>
  <option value="utcValue2">2 - 3 UTC</option>
  <option value="utcValue3">3 - 4 UTC</option>
  <option value="utcValue4">4 - 5 UTC</option>
  <option value="utcValue5">5 - 6 UTC</option>
</select>

<input value="whatever" type="checkbox" name="chkBox" class="custom-control-input" id="gameCheck">
<input value="otherwhatever" type="checkbox" name="chkBox" class="custom-control-input" id="purchCheck">
<input value="morewhatver" type="checkbox" name="chkBox" class="custom-control-input" id="inputCheck">
```